# Select query with join between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to get the result in a year-wise format but the following query returns an unexpected output:

```
    SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM Tab_1.DATE_STMP), COUNT (Tab_1.DATE_STMP), 

    EXTRACT (YEAR FROM Tab_2.DATE_STMP), COUNT (Tab_2.DATE_STMP) FROM  

    EMP_1 Tab_1 FULL OUTER JOIN EMP_2@LINK Tab_2  

    ON EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Tab_1.DATE_STMP)= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Tab_2.DATE_STMP)  

    GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM Tab_1.DATE_STMP),

    EXTRACT (YEAR FROM Tab_2.DATE_STMP);
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
2014    40  2014    20
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```
2014    800 2014    800
```

My long plsql solution is to iterate over the DATE values and query Count separately:

```
--PL/SQL
OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT DATE_STMP FROM EMP_1@LINK1 UNION SELECT DATE_STMP FROM EMP_2@LINK2'
FETCH cur INTO v_datVar;
...
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP_1 WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_STMP)='||v_datVar INTO v_Total2;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP_2 WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_STMP)='||v_datVar INTO v_Total2;
...
--PRINT VALUES HERE
```

Ques.

Is there a single select query to get this output? (Different type of join or join-condition to use?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to group every table in separate `select`:

```
SELECT TAB_1.YEAR1, TAB_1.COUNT1, TAB_2.YEAR2, TAB_2.COUNT2

FROM 
(SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_STMP) AS YEAR1, COUNT(DATE_STMP) AS COUNT1
FROM EMP_1
GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_STMP)) AS TAB_1

FULL OUTER JOIN

(SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_STMP) AS YEAR2, COUNT(DATE_STMP) AS COUNT2
FROM EMP_2
GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE_STMP)) AS TAB_2

ON TAB_1.YEAR1=TAB_2.YEAR2;
```

Comment: Do remove the `TAB_1.` and `TAB_2.` from the sub queries. Did give expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You full-outer-join records on DATE_STMP. So you'll get matches and mismatches (i.e. where a date has no match in the other table). Your result shows that you don't even have a sigle match, but only mismatches. However, it seems you are not at all interested in how many dates match. Moreover I daresay you seem not even interested in how often years match. You simply want to count records per year in the two tables. This has nothing to do with matching records and joins.

So: Get the counts first. Then join the results so as to get one record per year:

```
select coalesce(t1.the_year,t2.the_year), t1.the_count, t2.the_count
from
(
  select extract (year from date_stmp) the_year, count(*) as the_count 
  from emp_1
  group by extract (year from date_stmp)
) t1
full outer join
(
  select extract (year from date_stmp) the_year, count(*) as the_count 
  from emp_2@link on
  group by extract (year from date_stmp)
) t2 on t2.the_year = t1.the_year;
```

EDIT: I see you changed your request's query and join by year now. Still, as mentioned, I think you are not interested in counting matches and mismatches, so my answer stays the same.

Comment: Compared to the pl/sql code would a `select` query be more efficient?

Comment: Yes sure. With SQL you get directly to the data and this select is straight forward. With PL/SQL it is always calls from the PL/SQL engine to the SQL engine. This is fast, no doubt, but not as fast as to stay within SQL only.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `union all` with aggregation:

```
SELECT y1, cnt1, y2, cnt2
FROM ((SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Tab_1.DATE_STMP) as y1, COUNT(*) as cnt1, NULL as y2, NULL as cnt2
       FROM EMP_1 Tab_1
       GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Tab_1.DATE_STMP)
       EMP_2@LINK Tab_2  
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT NULL, NULL, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Tab_2.DATE_STMP) as y2, COUNT(*) as cnt2
       FROM EMP_1 Tab_2
       GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Tab_2.DATE_STMP)
      )
     )  
GROUP BY COALESCE(y1, y2)
```